# i have Error : unknown action type: addUserAction

Tags: vuex

I'm having a problem which is it gives me an error " [vuex] unknown action type: addUserAction " when I dispatch Action :-
here's my module called " HomePage "

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
state : () => ({
    categories : [],
    users : []
}),
mutations :{
    GET_CATEGORIES( state ,categories){
        state.categories = categories
    },
    ADD_USER(state , user){
        state.users.push(user)
    }

},
actions :{
    getEcommCategories({commit}){
        return axios.get("/api/ecommerceCategories").then(res =>{
            commit('GET_CATEGORIES' ,  res.data.data) ;
        })
    },
    addUserAction({commit},user){
        return commit('ADD_USER' , user)
    }
}
```

}

and this is my store :-

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex"
import * as HomePage from "./HomePage/home"

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
modules :{
    HomePage
},
state,
getters,
actions,
mutations,

})
```

so I try to dispatch action in methods like this

```
add(){
    this.$store.dispatch('addUserAction', this.user)
},
```

Comment: Isn't your action [namespaced](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing) somehow? Check your Vue devtools. Probably a matter of `this.$store.dispatch('myCoolNamespace/addUserAction', this.user)` or alike. The rest is properly called? Maybe an export thing?

Comment: @kissu the problem resolved but another error appeared " sub is not a function" when i try to dispatch action

Comment: I don't see `sub` in the given snippets, cannot help further.

Answer (score 0):

I think changing `import * as HomePage from "./HomePage/home"` to `import HomePage from "./HomePage/home"` in your store file might work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your answer , the problem happened because there was two stores in my project

Answer (score 0):

add namespaced: true to your module like this:

module:

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

root:

```
import customNamespace from ./customNamespace.js

modules: {
 customNamespace
}
```

component:

```
this.$store.dispatch('customNamespace/action', payload)
```

I personally like to define everything in constants:

```
const NAMESPACE = 'selectOption';

const GET_SELECT_OPTIONS = 'selectOptions';
const INITIALIZE_SELECT_OPTIONS = 'initializeSelectOptions';

export const GETTER_SELECT_OPTIONS = `${NAMESPACE}/${GET_SELECT_OPTIONS}`;
export const ACTION_INITIALIZE_SELECT_OPTIONS = `${NAMESPACE}/${INITIALIZE_SELECT_OPTIONS}`;

const state = {
  selectOptions: [],
};


const getters = {
  [GET_SELECT_OPTIONS]: (state) => state.selectOptions,
}

const actions = {
  async [INITIALIZE_SELECT_OPTIONS](context, payload) {
    ...
  }
}
const mutations = {
  ...
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

and then in my component i can use the action like this:

```
this.$store.dispatch(ACTION_INITIALIZE_SELECT_OPTIONS, payload)
```

or use mapActions by vuex:

```
methods: {
  ...mapActions({ initializeSelectOptions, ACTION_INITIALIZE_SELECT_OPTIONS}),
  async myMethod(){
    await this.initializeSelectOptions(this.payload)
  }
}
```

Comment: well gonna try this answer , thank you